# Permissions to edit IPv6 CIDR for IAM User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have given "AmazonVPCFullAccess" policy, which is a managed policy of AWS. But this policy does not allow IAM user to associate or disassociate the IPv6 CIDR block to the subnet. what policy permissions can I give to allow IAM user to remove or add IPv6 CIDR block in the subnet?

Comment: Frame the question better please , can you give examples or screenshot perhaps ?

Comment: @KushVyas thanks for the comment. I have updated the question. And I got my answer as well.

Comment: If you have got answer to your quest , please post answer on your own so that it helps community

Comment: @KushVyas posted my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following permissions gave the access to associate and disassociate Ipv6 CIDR to the IAM User

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [

                "ec2:DisassociateSubnetCidrBlock",
                "ec2:AssociateSubnetCidrBlock"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```